# angularjs - track by in a for loop

Tags: angularjs

I have a problem with the refresh button in my Angular application:

I have a json object with two arrays in it -> `data = {array1: [], array2: []}`

I want to loop both arrays and print the related values. To achieve that, I use the Angular `ng-repeat` directive like this:

```
ng-repeat="index in [] | index:getTotalNumberOfObjectsInArray1()"
...
<span ng-bind="data.array1[index]"></span>
<span ng-bind="data.array2[index]"></span>`
```

My Problem is, that on every click on the refresh-button these data will be recreated on the dom.
I learned the documentation about "track by" but i understand it only on objects (for example: ng-repeat="a in objects track by a.id")

How can I use this track by filter for my ng-repeat above, to prevent the recreation of my data?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$index` that is defined in a ng-repeat (cf.doc) but you have to have the two array with the same length.

Another solution could be to merge your arrays together and loop on it but I am not sure if it answer to your question.